# onTouch() event return only first touched child view

Tags: android

I have `GridLayout` as parent and 5x5 = 25 `TextViews` dynamically created as children's of `GridLayout`.

I want to do this: when I touch and move over child current touched child to change text. I try to implement `setOnTouchListener` on every `TextView` but `onTouch` is called every time , but view returned by `onTouch` is always the first touched child view.

```
for (int row = 0; row < 25; row++) {

  for (int col = 0; col < 25; col++) {
      final TextView textView= new TextView(this);

      textView.setText(Integer.toString(col));

      textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                            changeViewText(view);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                });

      gridLayout.addView(pixelView);

  }
}
```

Can someone tell me what I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The listener is keeping a reference of "textView" variable the first time it got created.

Change `changeViewText(textView);` to `changeViewText((TextView) view);` so that each listener affects the TextView it's attached to.

Comment: actually in my real code I  use view not textView. I edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Thats the way touch events are dispatched, since you first touched the first View, it had requested to consume ALL further events, when dragging the finger out of the view you will still receive events with the X,Y being out of your first View AT your first View listener.

The only solution for that is overriding dispatchTouchEvent at the GridLayout.

For example:

```
public class MyGridLayout extends GridLayout {
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    for(View v : getChildren())
        if (BoundsUtils.getBounds(v).contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
            v.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(e));
}

RectF getBounds(View v) { return new RectF(e.getLeft(), e.getTop(), e.getRight(), e.getBottom()); }
}
```

Comment: @Jovan Such code will work specifically to your behaviour, but what can I tell is such the one edited here